# How should I properly annotate / type hint a list of tuples in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

This is Python 3.10 and PyCharm 2022.1.2 Community Edition. I'm new to type-hinting and annotations. I understand Python is duck-typed, but want to provide some help for myself in my project for maintability.

My code:

```
def MyFunction(mylist: list[int]) -> list[tuple[int,str]]:
    mydict = dict()

    mydict[mylist[0]] = 'b'
    mydict[mylist[1]] = 'a'

    items_in_order = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

    assert isinstance(items_in_order[0], tuple)

    return items_in_order

print(MyFunction([100,250]))
```

When I hover over `return items_in_order` in PyCharm, it gives me a warning: `Expected type 'list[tuple[int,str]]', got 'list[int]' instead.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I confirm the problem, and it seems a problem in `.items()` (`keys()` and `values()` known the correct type). Write a bug report to PyCharm

Comment: Thanks! [So submitted.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54628/Type-hinting-with-items-doesnt-recognize-tuple)